# Solutions for managing multiple static websites using same code base

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, vue.js, hosting

So this is a general question about managing static websites that use the same code base. However there are a couple of configurations that will need to be dynamic based on the User.

A couple of prerequisites

**1. My code base is built using the Vue framework**

**2. The sites communicate to a separate code base backend by api with a unique url endpoint**

How The API Communicates

**1.The backend is designed to be multi-tenant so essentially any request made by user will be dependent on the configured api end point.**

**2.For instance my axios.baseURL could be mycompany.domain.com/api/endpoint or it could be anothercompany.domain.com/api/endpoint depending on which company a user works for...**

So currently with the structure I have built I am able to host my website on aws with a s3 bucket, or with any other static hosting solution. However I need a separate bucket for each companies instance of the website and any changes made to the code base have to be pushed to each instance. Below is the functionality I am seeking that have not yet found

**FUNCTIONALITIES**

1. Buckets code base is controlled by something like Github
2. Congifure separate api endpoints for each bucket instance

Is this something that can be found on aws or similar places such as azure? or is what I am looking for completely off base?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should separate any reusable logic that can safely be applied to each website to a node module and you should host this yourself. For the views / custom features, those should be in their own repository. You can trigger pipelines on `commit` to automatically roll out continuous integration to specified servers on a repository-specific basis.

For #2, it's more complex. One easy way is to make a new table called `api_users`, for instance. This will have 3 columns, `id`, `tenant_id` (or whatever your unique "tenant identifier" is) and `token` and `expiry`, where `tenant_id` is an FK to your `tenants` table. The token should just be a unique, long string.

Now you should pass that string on the frontend with any of your API Reqests. something like;

```
{
    headers: {
        'X-Tenant-Token': getTenantToken()
    }
}
```

Then in Laravel make new middleware for this:

```
php artisan make:middelware TenantValidityMiddleware
```

In the `handle` function, determine we need some logic:

```
if ($token = request()->headers()->get('X-Tenant-Token')) {

   app()->singleton(Tenant::class, function ($app) {
       return Tenant::whereHas('api_users', function(Builder $query){
          return $query->where('token', $token);
       })->firstOrFail();
   }); 

   return $next($request);
}

abort(401, 'Unauthorized access');
```

Now any dependency injected `Tenant $tenant` calls will automatically resolve your tenant for this API request.

Also, you can make sure that this is the case by adding:

```
session(['token' => $token]);
```

And you can add some safety to your container resolution logic in your AppServiceProvider:

```
$this->app->resolving(Tenant::class, function ($tenant, $app) {
    if (!$tenant->token === session('token') || auth()->user()->isAdmin()) {
        abort(401, 'Unauthorized access');
    }
});
```

This will help make sure that there are no forgery's going on during requests.

(the token property of tenant is resolved like this:

```
public function getTokenAttribute()
{
    return $this->tokens()->first()->token;
}
```

And of course you need to define the `token` relationship:

```
public function tokens(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(ApiToken::class, 'api_users', 'tenant_id');
}
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to write this response! I actually have my backend built to be aware of any tenancy requests and to validate each request however I appreciate your description. My interests are more in the `code-pipline` that you mentioned in the first part of you answer. I guess in short is there a way to have my static website code base linked to a repository? so i can have continuous roll out..

Comment: @TJWeems Of course! You will need a continuous integration service. GitHub will ping a special URL of your CI service whenever a commit occurs to a specific branch. Then you will build logic within the pipeline of the CI to build your application (website, etc) and push it to your servers that serve that. It may just be S3 or CloudFront, but it all works the same. Check out [buddy](https://github.com/marketplace/buddy) should be fairly reasonably priced. Alternatively you can do this with your own server, as well.